# How to search a character from a string android

Tags: android

I have 3 widgets on my screen, Text View, Edit Text and a Button. What ever I insert in my edit text, when I click the button, the text view gets the string from the edit text. Now, what I want to do is that, if I have already inserted the character "\" or "," or what ever character I want, it will not be inputted anymore. It's like, you can only put that character once in the edit text. Do you guys have any idea about it?

Well what I am thinking is that, I have to search from the edit view then validate it. But I don't know what code to use. Could somebody please help me? Thank you!

Comment: dont forget to accept answers to all your asked questions on stackoverflow. it is done by checking on right image on the left side of the answer

Comment: if someone helps you, then you should appreciate

Comment: I know I know sir, but I'm still working on it sir, if it really works, then I would accept it sir. Please concentrate first at the question. I know how to click that check mark sir. Don't worry ok? Please help me first with this problem. I know you guys are pro and you can help a noob like me. xD

Answer (score 3):

Use Android TextWatcher on EditText.

There are delegates which returns the charsequence that is entered

onTextChanged

afterTextChanged

beforeTextChanged

Fill the entered character in set everytime. If size is not incrementing that means a duplicate. 
then avoid adding of that character in edittext

Comment: Well, not yet. I am new on android/java programming. Can you please give me a sample code for it?

Comment: Just write on Google." TextWatcher examples android "

Comment: Now what am I supposed to do after i put these 3?

Comment: I already got the real answer. Thanks for the ideas. I already vote you up but I didn't accept your answer because it did not answer my question, but only gave me an idea. But still, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add a TextChangedListener to your editText.

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```